# How to reuse Elixir config across config files?

Tags: elixir

I have the following `mix.exs` file:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  hostname: "localhost"
```

I know, within the same file below, it's not allowed to do:

```
config :my_app, :postgres, Application.get_env(:my_app, MyApp.Repo)
```

because it returns `nil`.

Nevertheless, I'd expect to have it available in the other files, e.g. `runtime.exs`, but this doesn't work either and a `nil` value is returned as well.

**Is it possible to call `Application.get_env/2` inside a config file** to fetch configuration set in some another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to call `Application.get_env/2` inside a config file to
> fetch configuration set in some another?

No. Although this may technically be possible in some circumstances, as Aleksei has stated, this is discouraged.  Although perhaps not 100% technically accurate, when configuration is being read, *your app doesn't exist yet*.  You can use `System.get_env/2`, but not `Application.get_env/2`.

You can, however, include *other* config files from your compile-time configs.  The most common variant is to include environment-specific config files from your `config/config.exs` (i.e. the compile-time config):

```
import Config

# ...

# e.g. include config/dev.exs
import_config "#{config_env()}.exs"

# or include config/extra_config.exs
import_config "extra_config.exs"
```

You will notice that you may NOT use `import_config` from your runtime config file (i.e. `config/runtime.exs`).  Attempting to use it there will generate an error:

```
** (RuntimeError) import_config/1 is not enabled for this configuration file.
```

You can use `Code.eval_file/2` to "include" any `.exs` file -- the contents of the file are *returned* in a tuple.

```
Code.eval_file("config/extra.exs") |> elem(0)
```

You can use this approach to hydrate values in your `runtime.exs` with the contents of another file.  Remember that files evaluated in this way should NOT use `config`, they should only *return* values (maps, lists, etc), e.g.

```
# something.exs
[foo: :bar]
```

```
config :myapp, :something, Code.eval_file("config/something.exs") |> elem(0)
```

It's worth noting that the paths provided to `Code.eval_file/2` should be relative to the root of your app.  You can put files in folders other than `config/` but if you use other locations, you will have to customize your application builds to include and/or overlay the files so they will be available to the built app (whereas files inside the `config/` file are included in the build by default).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Config.import_config/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#import_config/1)

```elixir
if File.exists?("config/common.exs"),
  do: import_config("common.exs")
```

Comment: All files exist. And they are imported correctly.

Comment: I am lost. The above perfectly answers the question “How to reuse Elixir config across config files?” `Application.compile_env/3` won’t work because no `:application` exists yet during the compilation stage. If you want to reuse values, declare them with plain [tag:elixir] syntax (`repo = [foo: :bar]; config :my_app, MyApp.Repo, repo; config :my_app, :postgres, repo`.)

Comment: `Application.get_env/3` is discouraged during the whole compilation stage, btw, even in source files. Effective `v1.14.0` it results in a compilation warning.